# TypeORM doesn't support the database setting on the entity decorator

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to seperate my TypeORM project over multiple databases as it is growing in size, and its components are very discrete(yet interlinked, so i need to be able to have relations cross-database).

I am trying to do that using the `database` setting on the `@Entity` decorator, as described here: https://typeorm.io/#multiple-connections/using-multiple-databases-in-a-single-connection

I made a minimal reproducable example for this, with two entities that should in theory be put in different databases:

```
@Entity({ database: 'test' })
export default class Entity1 {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id?: number

    @Column()
    name?: string

    @Column()
    address?: string
}
```

and

```
@Entity({ database: 'database2' })
export default class Entity2 {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id?: number

    @Column()
    name?: string

    @Column()
    address?: string
}
```

Connection code:

```
import {createConnections} from "typeorm";

async function doDbExample() {
    const connections = await createConnections([{
        name: "db1Connection",
        type: "postgres",
        host: "db",
        port: 5432,
        username: "test",
        password: "testPassword",
        database: "test",
        entities: [__dirname + "/entity/*{.js,.ts}"],
        synchronize: true
    }]);

    console.log("Created connections")
}

doDbExample()
```

However, what happens is that both entities' table is put in the database of the connection. Am i doing something wrong, or is this a bug in TypeORM? It looks to me like it is not respecting the `database` setting any more.

I am running the code using `ts-node-dev`

I made a full minimal reproducable example, complete with dockerized setup of the database environment, on github: https://github.com/petterroea/TypeOrmBug-MRE

Answer (score 2):

This is a setup issue. I solved it like this:

1. Modify the array `entities` so each connection/database has its own folder with entity files and name the entity you use the most as `default`:

```js
// src/index.ts
 await createConnections([
      {
        name: 'default',
        host: 'SERVER1',
        username: 'bob',
        password: 'kiwi,
        type: 'mssql',
        database: 'db1',
        ...
       "synchronize": true,
       "entities": ["src/db1/entity/**/*.ts"],
      },
      {
        name: 'connection2,
        host: 'SERVER2',
        username: 'Mike',
        password: 'carrot',
        type: 'mssql',
        database: 'db2,
        ...
       "synchronize": true,
       "entities": ["src/db2/entity/**/*.ts"],
    ])
```

2. Create entity files for each database in its respective folder:

   - `src/db1/entity/Fruit.ts` > table in db1
   - `src/db2/entity/Vegetables.ts` > table in db2

With `"synchronize": true` each table will be created automatically in the correct database

3. Accessing data in the tables:

   - For the `default` connection::

```
import { Fruit} from 'src/db1/entity/Fruit.ts'
  fruits() {
    return Fruit.find()
  }
```

- For the non default connection:

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm'
import { Vegetable} from 'src/db2/entity/Vegetable.ts'
  vegetables() {
      return async () => await getRepository(Vegetable).find()
  }
```

or

```
  async vegetables() {
    return await getRepository(vegetables, 'connection2').find()
  }
```

I hope this helps someone else struggling with the same issues as you and me.

Comment: What I don't get is how Typeorm can't figure out what connection to use for each entity given that the "entities" path of the configurations don't overlap.
Also it could have decorators or params in the @Entity decorator to specify the connection.

Comment: @Petruza exactly. Maybe one should open a feature request for that on GitHub or something.

Comment: I am using a feature / module folder structure rather than entity/*.  So I would use the file name in each set of connection parameters    
DB1 ['./dist/features/**/*EntityDB1.js'].  and   DB2 ['./dist/global/**/*EntityDB2.js']